# How can I add empty space in LinearLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want my to make a compound controls by extending a LinearLayout, here is my code:

```
public class MemberView extends LinearLayout {
    private TextView contactName;
    private ImageView removeContact;
    private ImageView contactPicture;

    public MemberView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //Context thisContext = getContext();
    onCreate(context);


    }

    private void onCreate(Context context) {
    contactName = new TextView(context);
    contactName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contactName.setText("Mohammad");

    removeContact = new ImageView(context);
    removeContact.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    removeContact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);

    contactPicture = new ImageView(context);
    contactPicture.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contactPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

    setClickable(true);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    addView(contactName);
    addView(removeContact);
    addView(contactPicture);
    }
}
```

I want it to look like the following **UI Prototype**:

[image]

But the result of my code is:

[image]

I tried adding a VERTICAL LinearLayout and add some spaces to it, but no use:
Here is the edited onCreate code:

```
private void onCreate(Context context) {
    contactName = new TextView(context);
    contactName.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contactName.setText("Mohammad");

    removeContact = new ImageView(context);
    removeContact.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    removeContact.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_delete);

    contactPicture = new ImageView(context);
    contactPicture.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    contactPicture.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

    LinearLayout layout2 = new LinearLayout(context);
    layout2.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    layout2.addView(new Space(context));
    layout2.addView(contactName);
    layout2.addView(new Space(context));


    setClickable(true);
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    addView(layout2);
    addView(removeContact);
    addView(contactPicture);
    }
```

Comment: Try to use RelativeLayout instead of Linear

Comment: @No_Rulz In using RelativeLayout I have to use RelativeLayout.LayoutParams and .addRule, this requires widgets ids I tired .getId of a widget but no use. I used RelativeLayout in the XML and it is the perfect solution to my problem :)

Comment: @No_Rulz Nevermind, got it. I have to set the id in order to use getId of an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RelativeLayout will best serve your purpose here. Structure should be as such:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    // image layout, aligned to the right.
    <RelativeLayout horizontal alignParentRight >
    <ImageView contact icon>
    <ImageView deleteIcon alignBottom right of contactIcon>
    </RelativeLayout>

    // contact name
    <RelativeLayout fillparent leftof abovelayout>
    <Textview centerparent true  this will display contact name />
    </Relativelayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You are correct, but in code I could not set the relative positioning because I need the id of a widget if I used LEFT_OF for example. I tired getId but no use!!

Comment: so you are not using the xml at all ?

Comment: Yes. But I got it I have to use setId before using getId for each element.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put space because it is not the proper way.

Use **android:layout_width**.

1. set the `android:layout_width` of the children to "0dp"
2. set the `android:weightSum` of the parent
3. set the `android:layout_weight` of each child proportionally, i.e.:
   `weightSum="5"` with three children:

   - `layout_weight="1"`
   - `layout_weight="3"`
   - `layout_weight="1"`

For example (this is static, you have to try in dynamic):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```